# Find and classify the singularities of $\frac{1-e^z}{1+e^z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a problem in my introductory course in complex analysis. I think the singularities are poles of order 1 at $\{i(2n+1)\pi:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. I'm more confident that those are poles for $\frac{1}{1+e^z}$, and I think the zeros of $1-e^z$ at $\{i2n\pi:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ don't change this, but I'm less sure about that. Am I right?

Comment: note that it is also an alternative writing of $\tanh(z/2)$.

Comment: @zwim Isn't it $-\tanh(z/2)$?

Comment: yes, I forgot the sign, but it doesn't matter for singularities discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since the zeros of the numerator are never equal as the zeros of the denominator, the poles are the zeroes of the denominator, the points on the form $(2n+1)\pi i$, which all are simple poles since the derivative of $e^z+1$ is not zero at those points.
In all of that points the residue is the same and its value is $-2$